# Using heredoc inside a function changes syntax highlighting of code below it

Tags: php, heredoc

I am using `<<<heredoc heredoc;` inside a function (in a class) and it messes up the syntax highlighting of all the code below it.

It's fine using it outside the function - or on a single line within a function:

[image: php]

But if I use it in a function (not on a single line), it messes up the highlighting below it, and my editor (same in Atom or Sublime Text) seems to think it closes with the one outside the function and class.. what's happening?

[image: php]

```
<?php

class SimpleCMS {
    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $username = 'root';
    var $password = '';
    var $table = '';

    public function display_public() {

    }

    public function display_admin() {
        return <<<ADMIN_FORM 
        ADMIN_FORM;
    }

    public function write() {

    }

    public function connect() {
        mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password) or die('Could not connect to the database. ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->table) or die('Could not select database. ' . mysql_error())

        // build the database
        return $this->buildDB();
    }

    private function buildDB() {
        $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (title VARCHAR(150), bodyText TEXT, created VARCHAR(100)) MySQL_QUERY;

        return mysql_query($sql);
    }
}

<<<ADMIN_FORM

ADMIN_FORM;
?>
```

Comment: images of code are not well-accepted; please post the actual code itself.

Comment: I'm posting the images to show the syntax highlighting within my editor..

Comment: both is better since if we have to fix something, we won't have to retype everything or see if there are errors.

Comment: Error reporting would have helped here; being a parse error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your heredoc terminator needs to be in the leftmost column, i.e. without indentation. This is documented on PHP's website: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.
>
> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). **That means especially that the identifier may not be indented**, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including macOS. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

Change your current code:

```
    public function display_admin() {
        return <<<ADMIN_FORM
        ADMIN_FORM;
    }
```

To this:

```
    public function display_admin() {
        return <<<ADMIN_FORM
ADMIN_FORM;
    }
```

Comment: Cool - I assumed this was some limitation in the editor.  Thank you for the info!

Comment: @PaulCrovella - about time, I say!!

Comment: Oh man, that's so ugly :'( thanks for the quick and helpful answer though!